# Complete Server Backup

Tags: server, 16.04, backup

I am wondering about backups for my server. I had run a webserver with a LAMP stack on an old netbook for several years, and had never backed it up. Not best practice, but I digress. I recently purchased my first rackmount server, and I want to do things properly. It is a Raid 1 with 2 hard drives.

After spending many hours setting up and securing my webserver, with databases, virtual servers, etc, I would like to make a complete backup of my server.

I plan to do regular backups of both the server and the database seperately, but for now I would like to make a complete backup of the entire server, to where I could restore an entire server installation to the current state. Ideally I would like to back up to external hard drives.

What would be a good strategy to do this? I dont require remote backups. Sorry if I am asking the wrong questions here, but as a programmer I am trying to figure out the world of server admins.

If anyone can give me some good tips on making/testing backups for a ubuntu server I would appreciate it

Comment: I use rsync on a cron job to back up all my machines to a remote server, to a btrfs volume that i take snapshots daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) to make a backup of the whole disk partition that is very simple to use and fast to recover.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up using clonezilla and it was pretty easy